# Message which I sent from a client program to server program prints in client program C Linux

Tags: c, linux, server, tcp

I learn how application works themself by Internet. I wrote a client program which sends a message to a server program, then that message should be printed in a server program, but this message prints into a client program. Here code server program and client program, also header file to redefine some types.

There are not any errors and warning while compiling, so I didn't send a compiling process.

**server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#include "../main_values.h"

int main()
{
    int socket_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);                            //create a socket server
    int opt = 1;            
    setsockopt(socket_server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt));         //set an option to socket to
                                                                                    //if we ends working with 
    sockaddr_in addr_server;                                                        //socket connected with 
    addr_server.sin_family = AF_INET;                                               //ip address, free ip
    addr_server.sin_port = htons(2251);
    addr_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.222");

    int stat = bind(socket_server, (sockaddr *)&addr_server, sizeof(addr_server));  //connecting ip addr and socket
    if (stat == -1)
    {
        perror("ERROR");
    }

    sockaddr_in addr_client;                                                        //create the future client ip stucture 
    socklen_t len = 0;

    listen(socket_server, 15);                                                      //set server socket into listening
    int socket_client = accept(socket_server, (sockaddr *)&addr_client, &len);      //connecting client ip with our socket
    if (socket_client == -1)
    {
        perror("ERROR");
    }
    char msg[100];
    int res = read(socket_server, msg, sizeof(msg));                                //getting message from client
    printf("MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: %s\n", msg);                                       //printing message from client

    shutdown(socket_server, SHUT_RDWR);                                             //closing server socket

    return 0;
}
```

**client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#include "../main_values.h"

int main()
{
    int socket_client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);                                    //create a client socket
    int opt = 1;                                                                            //set an option like in a server.c
    setsockopt(socket_client, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt));               

    sockaddr_in addr_client;                                                                //making client ip structure
    addr_client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr_client.sin_port = htons(2250);
    addr_client.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);

    int stat = bind(socket_client, (sockaddr *)&addr_client, sizeof(addr_client));          //connecting ip and client socket
    if (stat == -1)
    {
        perror("ERROR");
    }

    sockaddr_in addr_server;                                                                //creating a server ip structure
    addr_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr_server.sin_port = htons(2251);
    addr_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.222");

    int socket_server = connect(socket_client, (sockaddr *)&addr_server, sizeof(addr_server));
    if (socket_server == -1)                                                                //connecting to server
    {
        perror("ERROR");
    }
    char msg[] = "HELLO WORLD!!!!!";                                                        //excample message
    int res = write(socket_server, msg, sizeof(msg));                                       //sending a message to server

    shutdown(socket_client, SHUT_RDWR);

    return 0;
}
```

**main_values.h**

```
#pragma once

typedef struct sockaddr sockaddr;
typedef struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_in;
```

**terminal_1**

```
ch@ch:~/Рабочий стол/mainc.4/my_server$ ./server.out
MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: 
ch@ch:~/Рабочий стол/mainc.4/my_server$
```

**terminal_2**

```
ch@ch:~/Рабочий стол/mainc.4/my_server$ ./client.out
HELLO WORLD!!!!!ch@ch:~/Рабочий стол/mainc.4/my_server$
```

Comment: A bit similar bug of the same nature but slightly different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529451/server-prints-to-stdout-instead-of-socket

Comment: Don't `typedef` structs, especially well-known structs. It serves no purpose.

Comment: I did that for me because I often forget to write `struct sockaddr_in`, or another same struct type, so I decided to redefine `struct sockaddr_in` to `sockaddr_in` and etc.

Comment: As an aside, note that your client sends `sizeof(msg)` `char`s thus omitting the null terminator so the server has no way of knowing the size of the message which will probably result in undefined behaviour.  Also, the server code assumes all of the data will be read by a single `read` call -- `tcp` doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: @G.M. If I want to send some message across the TCP, should I send a message which includes, for instance, 20 byte for sending with some cycle which will send in 2 bytes, for example?

Comment: With your current code the client should also send the null terminator and the server needs to read the data until it reads that null terminator.

Comment: @G.M. Okey, thank you!

Comment: @G.M. the `sizeof` includes the terminating null character if the string literal is assigned this way. So the client will already send the string over correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int socket_server = connect(socket_client, (sockaddr *)&addr_server, 
> ...
> int res = write(socket_server, msg, sizeof(msg));
> ```

The return code of `connect` is 0 if the connect succeeded. Thus `socket_server` is 0. This means a `write` to file descriptor 0 is done, which is the equivalent to stdin and thus results into a write to the terminal.

The correct code would be to write to `socket_client`, not `socket_server`. The naming suggests that there is some confusion of what `connect` returns, i.e. it returns a status and not a new socket. Please see [the documentation for connect](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works!!

Comment: Well spotted. This is a particularly nasty bug to identify.